# APA6: \citeauthor adds only the first author when citing a source for the first time

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa6

When citing a group of 3 to 5 authors for the first time in a paper using the document class `apa6`, the command `\citeauthor` adds only the first author followed by "et al.". The APA manuscript guidelines (6th version) require to refer to all authors in the first citation of the document. `\textcite` and `\parencite` work as expected, though.

This is what I get:

[image: wrong]

This is how it should look like:

[image: right]

Here my example:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber,doi,url]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@article{foobar,
  Author = {Foo, A. and Bar, B. and Baz, C.},
  Journal = {Journal of Foo},
  Pages = {1--2},
  Title = {Foo is bar},
  Volume = {1},
  Year = {1999}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\shorttitle{foo}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{foobar}
% \textcite{foobar}


\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\citeauthor*{foobar}`

Comment: A quick note: `apa6` is not a package but a *document class* in LaTeX terminology.

Comment: @Vivi: Unfortunately, this does not make a difference.

Comment: @Mico: You're right! I corrected the text.

Comment: @deboerk try using the option `natbib=true` (change the command in the preamble to `\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, backend=biber,doi,url]{biblatex}` and then using `\citeauthor*{foobar}`

Comment: @Vivi: Thanks a lot! Now it works. However, `\citeauthor*{foobar}` **always** adds all authors.

Comment: @deboerk yes, it does. I think you are supposed to use \citeauthor* for the first time, then without the asterisk for the following citations, which is not ideal, I agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following definition. I used the default definition of the bib macro `cite` and the command `cite` and removed the date.

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite:author}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
% Multiple cites in one command
   {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}%
% Single cite
   {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}}
% No author/editor
     {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
%       \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
%       \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
       \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
% Normal cite
     {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
        {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}}
        {\ifciteseen
          {\printnames{shortauthor}}
          {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{author}\addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
%      \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
%      \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
   \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:author}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly and is exactly what I wanted! It would be great to see this implemented in the apa biblatex style.

Comment: @deboerk: You can write an feature request to the author. ;-)

Comment: I'm the author and this was an oversight ... it's fixed in version 5.0 which will be released with biblatex 2.0/biber 1.0. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: @PLK: no oversight -- feature ;-)