# Redefine cite commands after first citation in biber

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I am using biber as a backend for biblatex with the alphabetic style. I want to work the textcite and citeauthor commands to work as follows:

If I use one of the above commands the first time for a certain reference, I want it to print all the author names. Then on further citations, I want it to only display the first authors name + "et al.". The way I did it until now is as follows:

```
    \DeclareCiteCommand*{\textcite*}{%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
    \defcounter{minnames}{99}%
    \defcounter{uniquename}{0}%
    \booltrue{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}
    }{\ifciteindex{\indexnames{labelname}}{}%
      \ifciteseen{\printnames[][1-1]{labelname}}{\printnames[][1-99]{labelname}}
    }{\multicitedelim}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

The problem with this is that for one thing I need to call \textcite* instead of \textcite and the other is that \textcite and \citeauthor are handled seperately here, i.e. if I call \textcite it works, but when I call \citeauthor for the first time it starts again with citing all names.
I would be very glad if somebody knew how to fix this.
Thank you.

---

Well, I noticed that the citation after the author's name(s) were ommitted if I called \textcite. Hence, I modified the command a bit like this:

```
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}{%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
    \defcounter{minnames}{99}%
    \defcounter{uniquename}{0}%
    \booltrue{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}
    }{\ifciteindex{\indexnames{labelname}}{}%
      \ifciteseen{
    {\printnames[][1-1]{labelname}\space\bibopenbracket}%
   \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}{}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}\bibclosebracket
    }{
      {\printnames[][1-99]{labelname}\space\bibopenbracket}%
   \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}{}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}\bibclosebracket
     }
    }{\multicitedelim}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

But using this code, I would get a citation that includes name and citation, but it also adds a space after the citation which does not look very nice. Does anybody know how to correct that?
Thank you?

@Seamus: I could not find any such feature in biblatex. If you know about something like this this would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, it works the way I stated above,

        \DeclareCiteCommand*{\textcite*}

needs just to be modified to

        \DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}

Comment: Doesn't biblatex already have this feature? I would have thought there would options to do this in biblatex already...

Comment: Using the \unspace command, one can delete the additional spaces before and/or after the citation.

Comment: This does look similar to [APA6: \citeauthor adds only the first author when citing a source for the first time](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60010/15647)

Answer (score 2):

The spacing issues are easy to avoid if you apply edits to the `textcite` bibliography macro instead of redefining `\textcite`.

There is another issue associated with the `\ifciteseen` test. It is appropriate when `labelname` is always part of the citation label. This is the case for author-year styles (e.g. [biblatex – et al. beginning from second citation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48846/4483)), but not `alphabetic`. A way around this is to track entries already cited via `\textcite` or `\citeauthor` using a `category`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{nameseen}

\newbibmacro*{labelname}{%
  \ifcategory{nameseen}
    {\printnames{labelname}}
    {\addtocategory{nameseen}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \printnames[][1-99]{labelname}}}

% Based on generic definition from biblatex.def
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \usebibmacro{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
% Based on definition from alphabetic.cbx
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifcategory{nameseen}
    {}
    {\clearfield{namehash}}%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\cbx@tempa
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{labelname}\space}%
     \bibopenbracket}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bertram2,
  title = {Gromov Invariants for Holomorphic Maps from Riemann Surfaces to Grassmannians},
  author = {Bertram, Aaron and Daskalopoulos, Georgios and Wentworth, Richard},
  journal = {Journal of the American Mathematical Society},
  volume = {9},
  number = {2},
  pages = {529--571},
  year = {1996}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Some filler text \parencite{companion,bertram}.
\Citeauthor{companion} showed that...
\Textcite{companion} showed that...
The results from \textcite{bertram,bertram2,companion}...
The results from \textcite{bertram,bertram2,companion}...
The results by \citeauthor{bertram,companion,yoon}...
\end{document}
```

[image]

This solution also works with BibTeX as the backend.

The `alphabetic-verb` style is similar to `alphabetic`, but it doesn't generate compact citation lists. To get the solution working with `alphabetic-verb` use the following redefinition of `textcite`.

```
% Based on definition from alphabetic-verb.cbx
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{labelname}\space}%
  \bibopenbracket
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}}
```