# print "author author author (short: author1 et al)" first time using \citeauthor

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

is it possible to change [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60228) solution (for printing all authors, when  `\citeauthor` is used the first time) that it prints

```
Author1, Author2, Author3 (short Author1 et. al)
```

?

changing the source to

```
\newbibmacro*{labelname}{%
  \ifcategory{nameseen}
    {\printnames{labelname}}
    {\addtocategory{nameseen}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \printnames[][1-99]  {labelname}\addspace\printtext{(kurz\addspace\printnames{labelname})}}}
```

doesn't work, because it does the same for single authors:

```
Author1 (short Author1)
```

Here the full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99, backend=biber,citetracker=true]{biblatex}


\DeclareBibliographyCategory{nameseen}

% old, but with no "short" in the parents:
%\newbibmacro*{labelname}{%
%  \ifcategory{nameseen}
%    {\printnames{labelname}}
%    {\addtocategory{nameseen}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
%     \printnames[][1-99]{labelname}}}

% new, but with the problem:
\newbibmacro*{labelname}{%
  \ifcategory{nameseen}
    {\printnames{labelname}}
     {\addtocategory{nameseen}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \printnames[][1-99]{labelname}\addspace\printtext{(short\addspace\printnames{labelname})}}}


% Based on generic definition from biblatex.def
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \usebibmacro{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
% Based on definition from alphabetic.cbx
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifcategory{nameseen}
    {}
    {\clearfield{namehash}}%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\cbx@tempa
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{labelname}\space}%
     \bibopenbracket}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
  \gdef\cbx@tempa{\bibclosebracket\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{foobar,
  Author = {Author1, A. and Author2, B. and Author3, C.},
  Journal = {Journal of Foo},
  Pages = {1--2},
  Title = {Foo is bar},
  Volume = {1},
  Year = {1999}
}

@article{foobar2,
  Author = {SingleAuthor, A.},
  Journal = {Journal of Foo},
  Pages = {1--2},
  Title = {Foo is bar},
  Volume = {1},
  Year = {1999}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}


\begin{document}

1. \citeauthor{foobar}\\
2. \citeauthor{foobar}
3. \citeauthor{foobar}
1. \citeauthor{foobar2}\\
2. \citeauthor{foobar2}
3. \citeauthor{foobar2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the problem is, that i don't know how to check , if `\printnames{labelname}` is different from `\printnames[][1-99]{labelname}`
i'm sure there must be an easy way to check if an "et. al"-truncation needs to be made or not.

Comment: It seems you need the test `\ifciteseen`

Comment: thank you :)

but that will not indicate, if there are more than 2 authors. the identification for first time vs. any other time works well. i need to avoid situations like "Author1 (short Author1)".

Comment: You need to look at the `liststop` counter and compare this with `listtotal` for the name list (see page 218 of biblatex manual). If there is any name list truncation to "et al" it means that `liststop` < `listtotal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer was intended only for the `alphabetic` style, where name labels appear only in `\citeauthor`, `\textcite` and their related commands. For the `authoryear` style you should probably adapt the solution in this post: [biblatex – et. al beginning from second citation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48846/4483)

In any case to test whether or not the name label is truncated you can compare the counter values `labelname`, `maxnames` and `uniquelist`. The `labelname` counter gives the length of the `labelname` list for the current entry. Typically this is the same as the `author` counter. Inside a citation `maxnames` corresponds to `maxcitenames`. When the biber-only `uniquelist` feature is enabled, the `uniquelist` counter corresponds to the length of the name label needed to disambiguate the `labelname` list from other entries.

```
\newcommand*{\iftruncated}{%
  \ifboolexpr {
    test {\ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{1}}
    and
    ( ( test {\ifnumgreater{\value{uniquelist}}{0}}
        and
        test {\ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{\value{uniquelist}}} )
      or
      ( test {\ifnumequal{\value{uniquelist}}{0}}
        and
        test {\ifnumgreater{\value{labelname}}{\value{maxnames}}} ) ) }}
```

This new test `\iftruncated{<true>}{<false>}` will expand `<true>` whenever the name label in the standard styles is truncated and expands `<false>` otherwise. To combine this test with your existing one, use:

```
\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcategory{nameseen}} or not test {\iftruncated} }
```